Does is the weighted L^p space, the completion of the "weighted" smooths function with compact support?
The completion of the space $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of smooth functions with compact support with the norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is the space $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1<p<\infty$.
Let $\eta=\frac{1}{w^{1/p}}$ with $w$ a weight function (non-negative and measurable function)
Question. If we define $C_{\eta,c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{\frac{1}{w^{1/p}}u\colon u\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$. Does is the completation of $C_{\eta,c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, the weighted $L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ space?
My attempt: Let $f\in L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. By definition, $w^{1/p}f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\left\|f_n-w^{1/p}f\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\to 0$, for some sequence $f_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This implies that $\left\|w^{1/p}(\frac{f_n}{w^{1/p}}-u)\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\left\|(\frac{f_n}{w^{1/p}}-u)\right\|_{L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\to 0$ for some $\frac{f_n}{w^{1/p}}$ sequence in $C_{\eta,c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Therefore, the space $C_{\eta,c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but, does is it the completion?
thanks.
